How to write sql update query so that sqlc can convert to golang function with optional paramters?
I'm writing a query that takes id and optionally updates two fields in that row. However I can't figure out a way to write the sql query in such a way that sqlc yields the desired golang functions.
I tried using CASE and empty strings to represent no update,  but the golang function created by sqlc uses generics and loses the column names.
When using coalesce, the golang function has string paramters (meaning no way to have optional updates). Does anyone have any ideas? I've attached copy of the query I wrote that leads to golang generics
-- Updates
-- name: someFunc :one
UPDATE table
SET
    name = CASE WHEN $1 <> '' THEN $1 ELSE name END
    default_content = CASE WHEN $2 <> '' THEN $2 ELSE default_content END
WHERE id = $3
RETURNING *;

Go code:

type UpdateParams struct {
    Column1 interface{} `json:"column_1"`
    Column2 interface{} `json:"column_2"`
    ID      uuid.UUID   `json:"id"`
}


sqlc needs a way to determine what Go type to use; often it can work this out from the context, but sometimes needs your help. The approach shown in the docs (but not really explained as far as I can see) is to type cast. For example:
UPDATE users
SET
    name = CASE WHEN $1::text <> '' THEN $1 ELSE name END
    default_content = CASE WHEN $2::text <> '' THEN $2 ELSE default_content END
    WHERE user_id = $3
RETURNING *;

Will generate the Go code:
type someFuncParams struct {
    Column1 string
    Column2 string
    UserID  int32
}

(I have made some guesses here re your data model).
If you want to take this a bit further you can do something like:
UPDATE table
SET
    name = CASE WHEN sqlc.narg(name)::text <> '' THEN sqlc.narg(name) ELSE name END
    default_content = CASE WHEN sqlc.arg(abc123)::text <> '' THEN @abc123 ELSE default_content END
WHERE id = sqlc.arg(user_id)
RETURNING *;

Will generate the Go code:
type someFuncParams struct {
    Name   pgtype.Text
    Abc123 string
    UserID int32
}

(note that narg signifies that the parameter is nullable).
